# In rails / Postgres using to_tsquery how do I search for a string inside a word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, full-text-search, where-clause

I have a search that works pretty well however there's one type of search that's missing.

So I have this which searches the 'name' column really well however it doesn't match strings where the search term is inside a word:

```
def self.search(query)
  query.gsub!(/[^a-z0-9\@\.\+]/i, ' ')
  where("(to_tsvector('english', name) @@ to_tsquery(?))", query.gsub(' ', '\\\\ ') + ':*')
end
```

For example:

Let's say the user searches for 'mpaign'

I would like titles with 'Campaigns' to be returned because 'mpaign' appears in it, however this isn't happening.

How do I go about making to_tsquery search inside words like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres text search can match full words such as `campaign`, or word prefixes such as `camp:*` for campaign, but not inside words, or by their endings.

You could *reverse* everything in a tsvector (`to_tsvector(reverse(name)`), and do a prefix search, such as `reverse('mpaign') || ':*'` for campaign.

Otherwise, you should use the LIKE operator with the % wildcard, preferably with a [trgm index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgtrgm.html).

```
where name LIKE '%mpaign'
```